# EXC_BAD_ACCESS during iterating through array of protocol witnesses

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, exc-bad-access

I'm a cocos2d developer and currently we are working on a Swift port. I've encountered into a very strange problem which I suspect is a Swift compiler bug, but maybe it is still me.

I have the following code

```
public protocol Tagged {
    var tag: Int { get set }
}

public protocol Component: Tagged {
    weak var owner: Node? { get /*set*/}

    func onAdd(to owner: Node)
    func onRemove()
}

open class ComponentBase: Component {
    public weak var owner: Node?

    open var tag: Int = 0

    open func onAdd(to owner: Node) {
        self.owner = owner
    }

    open func onRemove() {
        self.owner = nil
    }
}

public protocol FixedUpdatable: class, Prioritized {
    func fixedUpdate(delta: Time)
}

open class CustomComponent: ComponentBase, FixedUpdatable {

}

open class Node: Responder {
    // MARK: Components
    /// Array of components added to the node
    internal(set) public var components = [Component]()
    internal var fixedUpdatableComponents = [FixedUpdatable & Tagged]()

    public func add(component: Component) -> Bool {
        ...
        components.append(component)
        component.onAdd(to: self)
        ...
        if let c = component as? FixedUpdatable & Tagged {
            // TODO: Insert with priority in mind
            fixedUpdatableComponents.append(c)

            // If it is first component
            if isInActiveScene && fixedUpdatableComponents.count == 1 {
                scene.scheduler.schedule(fixedUpdatable: self)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Node: FixedUpdatable {

    public final func fixedUpdate(delta: Time) {
        fixedUpdatableComponents.forEach { $0.fixedUpdate(delta: delta) }
    }

}
```

// Then in Scheduler I have

```
for t in self.fixedUpdatableTargets {
    t.fixedUpdate(delta: timer.repeatInterval)
}
```

And it crashes during iteration, more exactly during execution of the first closure.

[image]

[image]

Should I file a bug to an Apple team? I tried a lot of things and none of them worked (recasting objects again in the closure, overriding tag property in many ways).

**UPDATE:**
This works:

```
    for c in fixedUpdatableComponents as [FixedUpdatable] {
        c.fixedUpdate(delta: delta)
    }
```

This doesn't:

```
fixedUpdatableComponents.forEach { $0.fixedUpdate(delta: delta) }

fixedUpdatableComponents.forEach { let c = $0 as FixedUpdatable; c.fixedUpdate(delta: delta) }

for c in fixedUpdatableComponents { c.fixedUpdate(delta: delta) }

for c: FixedUpdatable in fixedUpdatableComponents { c.fixedUpdate(delta: delta) }
```

Remember that `fixedUpdatableComponents` is `[FixedUpdatable & Tagged]`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this – please could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @Hamish I've got the same issue and described it in new question with simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449109/getting-exc-bad-access-in-foreach-closure